# pasting audio from one video file to another with a known time offset

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-editing, mencoder

I have two video files that also have audio tracks. I would like to copy the audio track of one file to the other with a 5000msec time offset.

The only problem is that the video files does not have the same duration, so I would like the resulted video files to have blank frames in the beginning/end if the audio starts before or ends after the video.

I'm looking for a command line solution that can be used on linux such as ffmpeg, mencoder etc.

EDIT:
run ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.9-4:0.8.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  9 2013 19:08:00 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2013-06-15 03:58:00
  Duration: 00:06:49.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3009 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720, 2814 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-06-15 03:58:05
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2013-06-15 17:25:15
  Duration: 00:06:59.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3159 kb/s
    Stream #1.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720, 2965 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #1.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-06-15 17:25:21
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Can you show some information about the input files and your ffmpeg build? The complete console output of `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2` will suffice. What are the exact offset times you want for each file?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard see my edit.

Comment: Just pointing out- you are using avconv/libav (not the real ffmpeg). When you say offset, you want the audio to start 5000 millisec after video? Then that is contradicting blank frames before audio start. Here one is 00:06:49.29 And the other is 00:06:59.09. Exactly how do you want the audio and video juxtaposed? If you can clarify a little more?

Comment: @Rajib I don't mind what tool to use as long as it will get the job done. I'm currently using the "ffmpeg" that was the default ubuntu 12.04 package. If I'll find a solution that works only with the real ffmpeg I'll use it.

Regarding the empty frames, if (because of the offset) the audio should start before the video or end after the video has ended I want there to be blank frames and just audio.

Comment: Generally you should use filter graph with filters trim, atrim and concat. And for blank screen you can use lavfi input. You have not answered Rajib's question, so I can't give you example command.

Comment: yes, I want the audio to start after the video. This way it will also end after the video has ended, I want the blank frames to be added after the video has finished but the audio has not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Let's assume you have `1.mp4` - video with with duration 30 sec, `2.mp4` - video with duration 30 sec, and you want to insert audio from `2.mp4` to `1.mp4` video with offset 5 sec. And also you need black video frames when video stream of `1.mp4` ends. So the command should be like:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=black:size=1920x1080:duration=5" \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v][2:v]concat[video_out]; \
 [0:a]atrim=duration=5[a1]; \
 [a1][1:a]concat=v=0:a=1[audio_out]" \
-map [video_out] -map [audio_out] out.mp4
```

This command does the following - we take `1.mp4` and `2.mp4` as input, and also generate 5 sec of video with black frames using lavfi. You may have another size of your input videos, so use the same same as `1.mp4` and `2.mp4` for lavfi (change `1920x1080` to whatever size your inputs are).

Then we combine `1.mp4` with black frames from lavfi with [`concat`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat), then we cut out first 5 sec of audio out of `1.mp4` with [`atrim`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) and combine it with audio stream from `2.mp4` (`concat` again). Then just specify that we want the output streams in `out.mp4`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That was not exactly what I wanted, but close enough for me to do the needed changes by myself.